# Umlaut not correctly displayed after Dropbox synchronisation

Tags: mac, texshop, dropbox

I want to work on my LaTeX Project on two different Mac Computers (using OS 10.12.5 and 10.11.6) and synchronise my files using Dropbox. My supervisor is controlling them using a Windows Computer.

The problem I'm facing is when I enter Umlauts such as äöü, the file on the other computer displays these as ‰^, or not at all when I use the other Computer first.

I tried using different encodings when creating the file with TexShop. The only Encoding that worked was Westeuropean (Mac OS Latin), but for this encoding I run into the problem that Windows Computers can't display it correctly.

Has anyone a solution to this?

Comment: use UTF-8 on all computers and make sure your editors on the mac and windows both default to that, really there is no need to use legacy mac or windows encodings now.

Comment: Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 got me displaying errors for Umlauts on the other mac

Comment: I don't know any tex system that can handle UTF-16 so it's not surprising that failed. UTF-8 will work if it is declared to latex and the editors on that machine are configured to use it, but without any further information impossible to say.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Using the starting line

"% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode"

did the trick! Now it works on both Macs and I'm confident also Windows will work

Answer (score 3):

Use UTF-8 on all computers and make sure your editors on the mac and windows both default to that, and that it is declared to latex as `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` . Really there is no need to use legacy mac or windows encodings now.